# How forEach works if we pass more than one argument?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I saw a javascript code where we have to print an array in the console.
I want to know how the value of i is initialised to 0 and how it is incremented.
Here is the code:

> var tos = ["Hello","Hi"];
> //To print this array
> tos.forEach(fuction(toso,i){
> console.log(i + " " + toso);
> });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: You mean how do they increment the counter inside the forEach? I don't know maybe with a ++?

Answer (score 0):

I think youre messing up forEach and a regular for loop. The forEach function is a regular (built in) function, that behaves quite similar as this:

```
function forEach(func){ // here you pass a function as parameter
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
       func(this[i],i);//now it is called
    }
}
```

So in your case, the built in function will do:

```
func("Hello",0);
func("Hi",1);
```

And thats what your parameters toso and i catch...

In your case you could also do:

```
tos.forEach(console.log);
```

Comment: Not relevant to this question, but there's also a third argument to `func` which contains the whole array

Comment: @user3080953 and theres a second argument to forEach that is bound to func. Bad i wanted to reduce the code as much as possible, so that it is easy understandable by newbies..

Comment: Understood, and I agree that your answer should stand as is.